# Алгоритм сортировки массивов уникальных чисел

Tags: python, алгоритм

Алгоритм предназначен для сортировки массивов длиной n, состоящих из уникальных чисел в диапазоне от 0 до n-1. Иными словами, массив должен содержать целые положительные числа от 0 до n-1, перемешанные как угодно. Например, если n = 8, то массив может быть таким:

**Массив длиной 8 элементов**
3 1 0 2 6 5 4 7  # В массиве содержатся все целые числа в диапазоне от 0 до 7.
Суть алгоритма: исходный массив разделяется на блоки так, чтобы каждый блок можно было отсортировать и при слиянии отсортированных блоков получился отсортированный массив. Менять блоки местами нельзя.

**Делим исходный массив на блоки, которые можно отсортировать:**
**Так нельзя**:после сортировки блоков их не объединить в отсортированный массив.
3 1 | 0 2 | 6 | 5 4 | 7

**И так нельзя.**
3 | 1 0 2 | 6 5 4 7

3 1 0 2 | 6 5 4 | 7  # А вот такое деление - в самый раз!

**Сортируем блоки:**
0 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7

**Объединяем блоки:**
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

**Получили отсортированный массив!**
Алгоритм сортировки состоит из трёх шагов:

Разбить исходную последовательность на k блоков. Блоки могут иметь разные размеры. Первый блок обязательно должен содержать 0. Если длина первого блока — r элементов, то максимальным значением в первом блоке должно быть число r - 1. А следующий блок (если он вообще будет) должен содержать число r. Этот принцип должен соблюдаться и в последующих блоках.
Отсортировать каждый из блоков.
Объединить блоки в единый массив.
Такая сортировка выгодна в том случае, если разбить исходный массив на максимально возможное число блоков.

В этом задании вам предстоит реализовать только первый шаг: разбить массив на блоки и вернуть их количество.

Задание: написать программу, которая получает на вход массив и возвращает максимальное число блоков, на которое можно разбить этот массив так, чтобы сортировка отработала корректно.

Ещё один пример:

3 2 0 1 4 6 5
Минимальный размер первого блока — 4.

Если взять лишь первые два элемента, то отсортированная последовательность будет начинаться с двойки, а это неправильно. Если взять первые три элемента, то последовательность будет начинаться с нуля, но после него сразу же пойдёт двойка. Опять нехорошо.

А вот первые четыре элемента гарантируют, что первая часть результирующего массива будет корректной.

Четвёрку можно взять как отдельный блок из одного элемента.

Последние два элемента составят третий блок. Таким образом:

первый блок: 3, 2, 0, 1;
второй блок: 4;
третий блок: 6, 5.
В этом примере ответ равен 3: чтобы сортировка блоками отработала корректно, полученный массив можно разделить максимум на три блока.

Формат ввода
В первой строке задано n — количество чисел для сортировки (n ≤ 1000). В следующей строке записаны числа от 0 до n - 1, которые надо разбить на блоки.

Формат вывода
Выведите максимальное число блоков, на которое можно разбить данные при использовании метода частичной сортировки.
Вот мой нерабочий код:

```
def sorting_blokcs(r):
    
    blok1 = []
    blok2 = []
    blok3 = []
    blok_count  = 0
    
    for i, item in enumerate(r):
        while (0 and 1) not in blok1:
            blok1.append(r[i])
            r.pop(i)
   #         print(blok1, r)
        if item == sum(blok1) or item == sum(blok1) + r[i-1]:
            blok2.append(r[i])
            r.pop(i)
       #     print(blok2, r)
   
        if len(r) > 1:
            blok3.append(r[i: len(r) // 2])
            blok3.append(r[len(r) // 2: len(r)])
            r.pop(i)    
            #print(blok3, r)
        if len(r) == 1:
           blok1.append(r[i])
           r.pop(i)
 #          print(blok1, r)
        if blok1:
           blok_count += 1
        if blok2:
           blok_count += len(blok2)
        if blok3:
           blok_count += len(blok3)
    #       print(blok1, blok2, blok3, r)        
        return blok_count
        #blok1, blok2, blok3
            
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    u = int(input())
    r = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    print(sorting_blokcs(r))
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: исправил всё, нормально?

Comment: Я думаю, код примерно раз в пять длиннее, чем требуется для решения.

Answer (score 3):

Конец блока - это позиция самого большого элемента в нём. То есть перебираем элементы слева направо, сохраняя самый большой элемент. Если он равен текущей позиции, то это конец блока. Инкрементируем счётчик блоков и переходим к следующему элементу массива и к новому блоку.

```
using System;
static class Programm {
    static void Main() {
        var ia = new int[] { 3, 1, 0, 2, 6, 5, 4, 7 };
        int nob = 0; int mx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ia.Length; i++) {
            if (ia[i] > mx) mx = ia[i];
            if (mx == i) nob++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(nob.ToString());
    }
}
```

Тоже взял идею у Станислава.

Comment: а можно в коде опишешь? не совсем понятно

Comment: Готовое решение, практически.

Comment: А вы правы. Отличное решение. Распишите кодом, или я его украду.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я не силён в Питоне, чтобы написать такой же красивый код.

Comment: Украл. Ну перетащите мой код к себе. Красивый ведь ответ.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вы не задали вопрос в вашем вопросе. Отвечать мне нечего. Но задача интересная:

- `a` - список чисел.
- `i` - текущая длина префикса списка.
- `flags` - для всех элементов `a[:i + 1]` установлены флаги.
- `below` - количество чисел в первой `i + 1` ячейке списка `a`, которые меньше или равны `i` (`sum(a[:i + 1] <= i`)).
- `blocks` - число блоков в `a[:i]`. Если `below` равен `i + 1` можно объявить новый блок.

Первоначально `below = 0`. В цикле с приходом нового числа `ai` значение `below` может увеличится на единицу двумя способами: если `ai < i` и если `flags[i]` - истина:

```
input()  # skip n
a = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
flags = [False] * len(a)

blocks = 0
below = 0
for i, ai in enumerate(a):
    flags[ai] = True
    if ai < i:
        below += 1
    if flags[i]:
        below += 1
    if below == i + 1:
        blocks += 1

print(blocks)
```

**P.S.** Предыдущий код слишком сложен. Вот, украдено из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1560037/416121) [rotabor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/510054/rotabor): блок объявляется когда максимум префикса равен его длине. Всё:

```
input()  # skip n
blocks = 0
max_so_far = 0
for i, ai in enumerate(map(int, input().split())):
    max_so_far = max(max_so_far, ai)
    if max_so_far == i:
        blocks += 1
print(blocks)
```

Comment: В Вашем коде (втором) есть рациональное зерно: масимум - это максимум не локально в блоке.

Comment: @rotabor, предыдущие блоки (их максимумы) не могут помешать последнему блоку (его максимуму). Это упрощает код.